# How to input a list of pairs of points in $R^2$ in sage corresponding to edges of a polygon, and to draw a picture of the corresponding polygon,?

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry, sage

Suppose I want to input in Sage a set of pairs of points corresponding to the set of edges of a polygon. For example, say I want to generate a (non-convex) polygon in $R^2$ with the set (list) V of vertices:

V= [[0,0], [1,0], [2,1], [2, -1]].

and the set of edges

E= [ [[0,0], [2,1]], [[2,1], [1,0]], [[2, -1], [1,0]], [[2, -1], [0,0]] ].

I'm not sure how to input E into sage so that for example, [[0,0], [2,1]] is understood as the unique straight line segment joining [0,0] and [2,1].

After that, I'd also like to generalize this to drawing a polyhedron in $R^3$ with the vertex set V, edge set E and the face set E.

Answer (score 1):

Is [polygon plotting](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/plotting/sage/plot/polygon.html#sage.plot.polygon.polygon2d) what you need?

```
sage: L = [[cos(pi*i/3),sin(pi*i/3)] for i in range(6)]
sage: polygon2d(L, rgbcolor=(1,0,1))
```

[image: filled polygon]

Or this one shows that it will always connect in exactly the order you give it:

```
sage: L = [[cos(pi*2*i/3)+random()*.2,sin(pi*2*i/3)+random()*.2] for i in range(6)]
sage: polygon2d(L, rgbcolor=(1,0,1),fill=False)
```

[image: unfilled polygon]

Otherwise you could use the fairly high-level [polyhedron](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/geometry/sage/geometry/polyhedron/constructor.html) functionality...

Comment: kcrisman: Thanks but I doubt this'd work for me. Apparently all the 'polygon' examples are actually triangles, except the following one:

sage: P = polygon([(0,0), (1,2), (0,1), (-1,2)])
sage: p = P[0]; p
Polygon defined by 4 points

It didn't give me any plot. But also, 'polygon defined by 4 points doesn't make sense, because the 'polygon=quadrilateral' defined by 4 points isn't unique. That's why we need to explicitly tell Sage what  vertices we want to join and what not to join, which I mentioned in my question. Formally, a polygon will be a graph with given vertices V and edges E.

Comment: Actually, I just tried

from sage.plot.polygon import Polygon
polygon([(0,0), (2,1), (1,0), (2, -1)])

This gave me only one possibility for the polygons with these vertices, not the other possibility. I guess what I need is a graph plotting software in or usable with sage that draws the graph for me when I specify the vertex and the edge set. I consulted the graph plotting section, but I didn't find any such command.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is.  Updating answer momentarily.

Comment: (And "Polygon defined by 4 points" is just shorthand.  `p.xdata` and `p.ydata` certainly will give you more info.)

Comment: Oh, you want graphs?  [The graph documentation](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html#sage.graphs.graph.Graph) includes information on how to *position* a graph.  But a graph and a polygon are quite different mathematical objects.  Why not ask a separate question about how to input a graph this way?  You should be able to even use the vertex points as names of the vertices, if you want.

Comment: Actually, every polygon P with vertex set V and edge set E could be thought as a graph G. So, if there's a way to input and plot the graph P=G with given coordinates of the vertices and given which edges we're joining, we're done.

Comment: Not the best solutin, but I tried this and it worked for the moment:

from sage.plot.line import Line
V= [[0,0], [1,0], [2,1], [2, -1]]
E=[[V[0],V[2]],[V[0], V[3]], [V[1], V[2]],[V[1], V[3]]]
line(E[0])+line(E[1])+ line(E[2])+line(E[3])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55178/discussion-between-mathmath-and-kcrisman).

Comment: No need, see next answer.  I finally see what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is a totally different pure-graph-theory way to do it.

```
sage: D = {'[0,0]':['[2,1]','[2,-1]'], '[1,0]':['[2,1]','[2,-1]']}
sage: G = Graph(D)
sage: D1 = {d:eval(d) for d in G.vertices()}
sage: G = Graph(D,pos=D1)
sage: G.show(axes=True)
```

[image: Graph in question]

Notice I **must** use hashable keys for the vertices, because it's a dictionary.

I guess you could also have a "master" dictionary which names things more reasonably and create both of these from it, but that probably requires a little more cleverness than I currently have this time of day.

Comment: And as for faces, I don't know, because faces definitely aren't necessary for graphs, and graphs in Sage aren't really 'embedded graphs', just combinatorial objects, most of the time.